# Can't find VLC header file

Tags: qt, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to compile a VLC-QT program but my compiler says it can't find `vlc.h`, even though I have included the path in my `.pro` file. Can anybody tell what's the problem with the following?

```
QT += core gui
TARGET = vlc
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
vlc_on_qt.cpp
HEADERS  += vlc_on_qt.h
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\QT Project\libvlc-qt_0.5.1_win32_sdk\include\
LIBS += -LC:\Qt\QT Project\vlc\libvlc-qt_0.5.1_win32_sdk\lib
LIBS += -lvlc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#include <vlc/vlc.h>` The library stores its header files in a separate directory as most libraries do.

Comment: i have included the header file in lib folder..but still can't find the header file...what should i do than ???

Comment: Don't put it in the lib folder, that's not where the compiler is looking. It should be in the include folder.